# Installing winehq-stable

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

When I run the command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I get an error. I tried a thousand times, but nothing happened!

This is my output picture:

[image: error message]

I followed this guide: [How to Install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-20.04.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text into your question (it's easier to read, plus we can copy text & use it to look up details for you in response).  You should also provide release details (there is mention of *focal* in the picture, but if you're not using 20.04 then this is a huge clue as to your issue)

Comment: Why don't you just install `wine` like this: `sudo apt install wine`

Comment: Please carefully follow official guide from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and then report back.

Comment: i tried a lot but not able to make it!. idk if Ill try in the future or not!